# Choosing sample from large dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, sampling

How to choose sample from a large dataset such that each unique row from the dataset is selected at least once in the sample? Is there a way of doing this in python?

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are asking. Could you rephrase the question?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a dataframe with 10,000 rows, and  you have only 1,000 unique ones.

You can do:

```
df_unique = df.drop_duplicates()
df_sample = df.sample(n)

df_final = pd.concat([df_unique, df_sample], axis=0)
```

In the above code, n is the amount of sample you want.
In this way you can assure that every unique row is in your dataset and you have more samples on it.